# Route the path and component name by looping in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

This is my route file coding. I have to create all route by get details from backend in asp.net. here I am getting Details properly from backend. this is my list of menus [Contacts, Pipelines, Stages ]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout,LayoutLogin } from './components/Layout';
import { Contacts } from './components/Contact';
import { Stages } from './components/Stage';
import { Pipelines } from './components/Pipeline';
import { Workspace } from './components/workspace';
import { NoMatch } from "./components/NoMatch"
import { Switch } from 'react-router';



var renderArea;

renderArea = <Layout>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Workspace} />    
        <Route exact path='/Contacts' component={Contacts} />
        <Route path='/Stages' component={Stages} />
        <Route exact path='/Pipelines' component={Pipelines} />   
        <Route component={NoMatch} />

        </Switch>
    </Layout>;

export const routes = renderArea
```

This the code I am trying to  route the path and components.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout,LayoutLogin } from './components/Layout';
import { Contacts } from './components/Contact';
import { Stages } from './components/Stage';
import { Pipelines } from './components/Pipeline';
import { NoMatch } from "./components/NoMatch"
import { Switch } from 'react-router';

import * as axios from 'axios';

var renderArea;
let renderMenuArea;
function listOfMenus() {
    axios.default({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/Access/GetAllMenusForRoutes',
    }).then(data => {
        debugger
        if (data.data.status == 'success') {
            var listOfallMenus = data.data.listOfallMenus;
            renderMenuArea = listOfallMenus.map((menu: any) => {
                return (<Route key={menu.name} exact path={'/' + menu.name + ''} component={menu.name} />)
            })
        }
        });
    return renderMenuArea;
}



renderArea = <Layout>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Workspace} />

        {this.listOfMenus()}


        <Route component={NoMatch} />

        </Switch>
    </Layout>;

export const routes = renderArea
```

This code is not working. return function data is always get undefined Please suggest me to get return data by modifying my codes or is there any way to do my purpose of code?

Comment: the `renderMenuArea` is variable not a function. Thats why  `{this.renderMenuArea()}  ` wouldn't work.

Comment: sorry, I edited this code this one also not working

Answer (score 0):

The function `listOfMenus` has an asynchronous call using the `axios`. so the code fragment where `renderMenuArea` is assigned the value is the success of the `axios` call. Since the call is asynchronous, the `renderMenuArea` is returned before the promise in the axios is resolved.

The best way to resolve this is to either use a proper state management framework such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) to store data and manage your view effectively.

The workaround to this would be using `async/await` in following way:

```
async function listOfMenus() {
    await axios.default({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/Access/GetAllMenusForRoutes',
    }).then(data => {
        debugger
        if (data.data.status == 'success') {
            var listOfallMenus = data.data.listOfallMenus;
            renderMenuArea = listOfallMenus.map((menu: any) => {
                return (<Route key={menu.name} exact path={'/' + menu.name + ''} component={menu.name} />)
            })
        }
    });
    return renderMenuArea;
}
```

I would highly recommend using any state management framework.

Comment: Thanks, How can I call this function into the render area. It gives error like this "Uncaught TypeError: this.listOfMenus is not a function" ;

Comment: It does not work. when I print renderArea `2: Promise {<resolved>: Array(11)}`

Comment: the values are geting extracted in `Array(11)`. Can you put debug points and debug through the values in order to extract the value ?

Comment: I do not  know. I tried :(. Is there any specific way to extract promise array

Comment: you can use a callback to assign the value.